# Add finings to beer to be bottled?

Tags: bottling, fining

I've got a chocolate stout fermenting at the moment, and I'd like to add finings to this once fermentation is complete.  I haven't done this before, so wondering what the best method is?  I'll be bottling this beer, I assume I need to add the same amount of brewers sugar to each bottle like I normally would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with both answers above, but why add finings to a stout? You can get most yeast out of suspension in secondary, with a little chilling.  Further clarification can be achieved with finings, but in a stout the results won't be noticeable.

Comment: I completely agree with "why add finings to a stout?".

Answer (score 2):

Do it by batch, much like adding priming sugar.

Answer (score 0):

PMV is right on but make sure to let it sit after fining too, don't bottle it right away, let everything settle out before bottling, a week or two should be good.